# web service connection with WebProxy

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, proxy

I have a connection to a web service with an option to add proxy details.  This works fine.  However, it seems to fail when the proxy is not just an address, but and address with a file name... for example;

```
myproxy.com/proxypac.asp
```

It is this filename at the end that seems to be giving me issues.  I am initialising my WebProxy as such;

```
System.Net.WebProxy wp = new System.Net.WebProxy(location.ProxyAddress, location.ProxyPort);
```

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: "it seems to fail"... with which exception? how do you know for certain?

Comment: Have a look at this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300743.aspx

Comment: the error is simply; 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(@"http://myproxy.com/proxypac.asp");
```

Or

```
WebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

A workaround would be to open your file and check its content to see the proxy adress and port you get.

If you download your `myproxy.com/proxypac.asp` file it should look like this :

```
   function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
      // our local URLs from the domains below example.com don't need a proxy:
      if (shExpMatch(url,"*.example.com/*")) {return "DIRECT";}
      if (shExpMatch(url, "*.example.com:*/*")) {return "DIRECT";}

      // URLs within this network are accessed through 
      // port 8080 on fastproxy.example.com:
      if (isInNet(host, "10.0.0.0",  "255.255.248.0"))    {
         return "PROXY fastproxy.example.com:8080";
      }

      // All other requests go through port 8080 of proxy.example.com.
      // should that fail to respond, go directly to the WWW:
      return "PROXY proxy.example.com:8080; DIRECT";
   }
```